# Nested dispatch function does not get update props

Tags: react-redux

app.js

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {home:state}
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        guestLogin: (data)=>{dispatch(guestLogin(data)).then(()=>{
            dispatch(initiateTrans(stateProps.home))
        })},
    };
}

const mergeProps = (stateProps, dispatchProps, ownProps) => {
    return Object.assign({}, ownProps, stateProps, dispatchProps,{
        initiateTrans: () => dispatchProps.initiateTrans(stateProps.home),
    })
}
```

Action.js

```
export const guestLogin= (state)=>{
    var data={
        'email':state.email,
        'name':state.name,
        'phone_number':state.ph_number,
        'phone_code':state.country_code
    }
    return function(dispatch) {
        return dataservice.guestSignup(data).then(res => {
            dispatch(afterLoggedGuest(res))
        }).catch(error => {
            throw(error);
        });
    }
}


function afterLoggedGuest(result) {    
    return {type: guestLoginChange, result};
}


export const initiateTrans= (updatedState)=>{    
    return function(dispatch) {
        return dataservice.initiateTransaction(updatedState).then(res => {
            console.log("initiateTransaction",res)
        }).catch(error => {
            throw(error);
        });
   }
}
```

Reducer.js

```
if(action.type === guestLoginChange){
        return {
            ...state,guestData: {
                ...state.guestData,
                Authorization: action.result.authentication ,
                auth_token: action.result.auth_token ,
                platform: action.result.platform
            } ,                  
        }        
  }
```

I am having two api requests.. After first api request success i want to update state value then pass that updated state to another api request..

I tried to get the updted props
how to dispatch the initiateTrans with update props
I need to update value at api request success in call back i need to call one more request with updated state value

currently i am not able to get the update props value

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a good use case for thunk ([redux-thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk)), which is a middleware that allows you to execute multiple dispatches in an action.

You will need to apply the middleware when you configure the initial store (see docs on link above). But then in your actions, you can wrap the code with a dispatch return statement, which gives you access to multiple calls. For example:

```
export const guestLogin= (state)=>{
    return dispatch => {    
        var data={...} // some data in here
        return dataservice.guestSignup(data).then(res => {
            dispatch(afterLoggedGuest(res))
        }).catch(error => {
            throw(error);
            // could dispatch here as well...
        });
    }
}
```